# How do you unit test a function within a controller in titanium using jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, titanium, jasmine, titanium-alloy

Controller function:

controllerexample.js

```
function test() {
    return "works!";
};
```

controllerexample_specs.js

```
it('test controllerexample function.', function() {
    $ = Alloy.createController('controllerexample', {});

    expect($.test).toEqual('works!');

});
```

When I run the script, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] :  .  THERE WERE FAILURES!
[ERROR] :  .  ============================================================
[ERROR] :  .  Recap of failing specs:
[ERROR] :  .  ------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] :  .  controllerexample controller test controllerexample function.. - Expected Function to equal 'works!'
```

Comment: Try changing it to `$.test()` for starters, see if that changes anything

Comment: cheers that worked if I set up my function like this:
 $.test = function() {
 return true;
 };
Otherwise it complains that it is undefined.

Do I always have to expose it that way?

Comment: When I attempt the same as listed in code, I get `Failures:

  1) util tests encountered a declaration exception
   Message:
     ReferenceError: Alloy is not defined
   Stacktrace:
     ReferenceError: Alloy is not defined
    at null.<anonymous>

Finished in 0.005 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure, 0 skipped`